# Can I avoid the need to use the template disambiguator in a series of function calls?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template builder/factory class that makes objects of type `Foo`, where the `make()` method is a template method, like so:

```
template<typename T1>
class FooMaker
{
  template<typename T2>
  Foo make(...) { ... }
};
```

The idea here is that `T1` is bound to the builder since it's the same for all `make()` invocations, while `T2` (which is always a function name) is usually different for each `make()` call.

I'm calling `make()` many times to create different types of objects, and the combination of a template class and a template functions [means I have to use the `template` disambiguator before every call to make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/149138):

```
template <typename MAKER_T>
void make_some_foos()
{
    auto maker = FooMaker<MAKER_T>(...);
    Foo foo1 = maker.template make<Type1>(...);
    Foo foo2 = maker.template make<Type2>(...);
    // etc...
}
```

I'd like to needing the `template` keyword on each line that constructs a `Foo` above. In general I have many calls to `make()` on each `FooMaker` object, so a small amount of additional code when creating the factory would be fine.

Evidently I could do this using a macro which hides the `template` detail, but is there a good non-macro solution<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> I could move `T1` and `T2` to the same level - by making them both class template arguments, or both function template arguments, but the former would need a distinct maker for every new type `T2` and the latter means redundantly specifying the same `T1` in every `make` call.

Comment: If both `decltype(maker)` and `Type1` aren't dependent types, I believe you can just write `maker.make<Type1>(...);`. I'm not sure on the exact rules for it, though.

Comment: @Justin `Type1` is always a function. What does it mean though for `decltype(maker)` to be dependent? Does it depend on the nature of `T1`? Sometimes `T1` is a plan (non-template class), and sometimes it is a template class (but I could perhaps change this).

Comment: you could make `make` a standalone function that takes `Maker` as a parameter like a `std::tuple` getter

Comment: You can omit the `template` only if the type of `maker` is non-dependent, which means it doesn't directly or indirectly depend on any template parameters.  (`Type1` doesn't matter for that.)  Dependent types only exist inside template definitions.

Comment: @aschepler - thanks, I updated the calling example to make it clearer that the creation of `FooMaker` is itself generally inside a template function where the function template parameter is used for `T1` in `FooMaker<T1>`. Do I understand you correctly that if the `T1` was simply some type like `int` (using a `FooMaker<int>`) then it would be non-dependent?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Exactly.

Answer (score 6):

This is one big reason [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) is a non-member function, rather than a member of `std::tuple`.  Taking an idea from that pattern, you could create a non-member `make_foo`:

```
template <typename T2, typename T1, typename... Args>
Foo make_foo( FooMaker<T1>& maker, Args&& ... args ) {
    return maker.template make<T2>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then just use it like:

```
auto maker = ...; // some code to construct the builder
Foo foo1 = make_foo<Type1>(maker, ...);
Foo foo2 = make_foo<Type2>(maker, ...);
// etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could ensure that `T2` is deduced. To this end you need an argument that somehow provides the information. This could be a simple tag type

```
template<typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template<typename T1>
class FooMaker
{
  template<typename T2>
  Foo make_internal(...) { ... }
public:
  template<typename Tag>
  Foo make(Tag, ...)
  { return make_internal<Tag::type>(...); }
};

auto maker = ...; // some code to construct the builder
Foo foo1 = maker.make(tag<Type1>{}, ...);
Foo foo2 = maker.make(tag<Type2>{}, ...);
// etc...
```

or an enum in combination with a traits type, or you can simply use a pointer to pass in the type:

```
template<typename T1>
class FooMaker
{
public:
  template<typename T2>
  Foo make(T2*, ...);
};

auto maker = ...; // some code to construct the builder
Foo foo1 = maker.make((Type1*)0, ...);
Foo foo2 = maker.make((Type2*)0, ...);
// etc...
```

though arguably, this is not very elegant.

Comment: Thanks! Can this be extended to the variant where rather than `template<typename T2> make(...)` I have `template<func_t F> make()` where `func_t` is a function typedef?

Comment: @BeeOnRope In that case, wouldn't you passing in the functor `F` (which could be a lambda) anyway? Perhaps you should make an example (or another post).

Comment: No, it's always a plain function, never a lambda or other stateful thing like `std::function` so I'm using the template function argument feature, and nothing is passed as arguments but the template argument is just "directly called", e.g., `typedef void (*func_t)(int); template <func_t F> call_f(/* no args! */) { F(42); }`. You are right though that it's different enough that I should perhaps create a new question.